# Перемещение элементов в приложение при помощи мыши

Tags: javafx, drag-n-drop

Мне нужно написать простой аудио проигрыватель, хочу сделать область - плейлист, чтобы в нее можно было перетаскивать/добавлять файлы из любого места. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Благодарю за изменение тегов, тег dragndrop помог мне найти ответ, и еще видео нашел https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7KGXUrAH0g

```
 setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                if (event.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                }
            }
        });

        setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                List <File> fileList = event.getDragboard().getFiles();
                File file = fileList.get(fileList.size()-1);
                String fileName = file.getName();
                if (fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != -1 && fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != 0) {
                    if (fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1).equals("mp3")) {
                        bord.getInfoCentr().getNameMusic().setText(file.getName());
                        if (bord.getOpenFile().soundFile.getMediaPlayer() != null) {
                            MediaPlayer player = bord.getOpenFile().soundFile.getMediaPlayer();
                            player.stop();
                        }
                        bord.getOpenFile().soundFile.setData(file);

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("name last = "+file.getName());

            }
        });
```